# Find three consecutive zero in dataset in R

Tags: r

I need to find whether there are three consecutive zero in the `Balance` column in data-frame. I need to check whether the balance is zero for 3 consecutive months within particular `RelNo`. It is a large dataset. My dataframe looks like this:

```
------------------------------------
RelNo   -----Date   --- -----    Balance
--------------------------------------
AAAA    ---- 1/1/2014 ----       0
-------------------------------------
AAAA    --- 2/1/2014  ----       0
-------------------------------------
AAAB    --- 1/1/2014  ---       22
------------------------------------
AAAB    --- 2/1/2014 ---        2
-----------------------------------
AAAA    --- 3/1/2014 ---       0
---------------------------------
AAAA    --- 4/1/2014 ---       0
--------------------------------
AAAB    --- 3/1/2014 ---      32
-------------------------------
AAAC   ---- 1/1/2014 ---      45
----------
```

Comment: Do you want to order by 'Date' and then check the consecutive 0's?  If so, what will be the expected otuput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps we can do this with `data.table` to create an logical column.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), `order` by 'RelNo' and 'Date' (after converting to `Date` class), grouped by 'RelNo' and run-length-id of logical vector (`Balance==0`), we check whether `all` the values in 'Balance' is 0 and if the number of rows is greater than 3 (`.N >=3`) and assign (`:=`) the logical output to 'ind' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(RelNo, as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y")), 
         ind := all(Balance==0) & .N >=3, .(RelNo, rleid(Balance==0))]
df1
#   RelNo     Date Balance   ind
#1:  AAAA 1/1/2014       0  TRUE
#2:  AAAA 2/1/2014       0  TRUE
#3:  AAAB 1/1/2014      22 FALSE
#4:  AAAB 2/1/2014      24 FALSE
#5:  AAAA 3/1/2014       0  TRUE
#6:  AAAA 4/1/2014       0  TRUE
#7:  AAAB 3/1/2014      32 FALSE
#8:  AAAC 1/1/2014      45 FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks I need to order by date. And the solution is working